# how to calculate the overall probability of destination given 2 different approaches?

Tags: probability

Bare with me, I hope I present the question properly:

Say I have 2 cars: car1 and car2; they have the following probabilities of destination:

```
Car    Destination      algo_A     algo_B
car1   London           66%         30%
car1   Paris            34%         70% 
car2   London           10%         90%
car2   Brussel          80%          5%
```

We favor algo_A over algo_B because it is calculated by repeated pattern.

**My struggle**: If you look at car2 is has a high likelihood to arrive to London **but** with an unfavored algorithm: algo_B. And if we look carefully we can see that it has a very high likelihood to arrive to Brussle with a favored algo_A.

**My Question**, in this case -what is the overall probability of car2 to arrive to London given that it has a strong algo_A to arrive to Brussel (80%)?

Put it differently, how to calculate each car's probability of destination given 2 different approaches?

**Edit**: if helps, we can assume favoring algo_A (70%) over algo_B at (30%)

Comment: Your percentages do not sum to $1$...

Comment: @Momo, yes, that is possible; Algo_A and Algo_B has nothing to do with each other. And the sum of Algo_A might not be 1.

Comment: But for algo_B, the probabilities for car2 sum to $110\%$. And what are algo_A, algo_B BTW?

Comment: @Momo thank you! corrected. The algos are 2 different algorithm that we receive from 2 different sources. They are de facto the results for each car destination.

Comment: You have to quantify how much you favor one algorithm over the other. Then you could weight the probabilities accordingly.

Comment: @EthanBolker ok,I edited and added 70/30 to algo_A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you estimate the probability that car 1 goes to London as
$$
0.7 \times 0.66 + 0.3 \times 0.30 = 0.55, 
$$
which weights each separate estimate in proportion to your opinion of its accuracy.

Calculate the other probabilities similarly.

Comment: Thank you. Followup question: say, in the solution you provided,  in event algo_a does not exist  - should I consider the 0.30 as is (without 0.3x0.30)? Thanks again!

Comment: If you have just one data point then that is your best estimate. If you have three, weight them with your estimate of their reliability.

Comment: got it. Thank you very much